# Cannot find UEFI secure boot option

Tags: uefi, bios, secure-boot

I have a Lenovo Ideapad y510p.

I have been trying to install CUDA for GPU computing, but I've been unsuccessful so far. One common instruction is to disable the UEFI secure boot.

The option simply doesn't exists when I enter the BIOS

[image]

The current BIOS I have is BIOS LENOVO 74CN44WW(V3.05), 9/18/2013. The latest that exists is V3.08, released in March of 2015. I believe it might not be related.

Comment: That BIOS looks like it predates UEFI.

Comment: Oh, I see. The would imply that I just shouldnt care about disabling it.